# How can i provide VPN access for my .net webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, networking, vpn

I have to provide VPN access to .net web service. Clients should access the service through VPN. Without VPN access clients can't access the data. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN is a network/infrastructure layer service that has to be set up by your hosting provider/operations departments. It's main advantage is that you set it up once on network level and then you can access all resources of the protected network without having to set up encryption etc. on every single service.

For just one web service it is easier and equally safe to use TLS (https) with a proper and strong authentication (e.g. requiring the client to use a certificate for authentication).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my service in dedicated server. I have to  provide VPN for it. Clients should access through it.

Comment: do u have any examples r samples of it? please help me.